# Capture HWND with context menu

Tags: java, winapi, capture

I am using WinAPI to capture the windows in Java.

```
public static BufferedImage capture(Pointer hWnd2, String wText) {
   HWND hWnd = new HWND(hWnd2);
   boolean success;
   if(User32Extra.INSTANCE.IsIconic(hWnd))
   {
       success= User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd, 4);
       System.err.println(success);
       System.err.println(wText+Native.getLastError());
   }
   HDC hdcWindow2 = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hWnd);
   HDC hdcMemDC = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow2);
   success = User32Extra.INSTANCE.PrintWindow(hWnd,hdcWindow2,1);
   RECT bounds = new RECT();
   RECT bounds1 = new RECT();
   User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hWnd, bounds);
   User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetClientRect(hWnd, bounds1);

   int extraGap = (bounds.right-bounds.left-bounds1.right);
   int width = bounds.right-bounds.left-extraGap;
   int height = bounds.bottom-bounds.top-extraGap ;
   HBITMAP hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow2, width, height);

   HANDLE hOld = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hBitmap);
   GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC,0, 0, width, height, hdcWindow2, bounds.left+bounds1.right-bounds.right+extraGap, bounds.top+bounds1.bottom-bounds.bottom+extraGap, WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hOld);

   BITMAPINFO bmi = new BITMAPINFO();
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
   Memory buffer = new Memory(width * height * 4);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcWindow2, hBitmap, 0, height, buffer, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

   GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteDC(hdcMemDC);
   User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow2);

   return image;
}
```

This code captures the HWND specified window. But if the user opens the context menu or menu bar options. Those are not being captured.

How to capture context menu of the window?

Comment: Maybe it's unrelated to your problem, but why are you using `PrintWindow` to print the window on itself, then blit it to memory ? You should either print to mem DC or blit to mem DC. Maybe the results will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `GetDesktopWindow()` to capture entire screen, then pass window coordinates to `BitBlt` to copy only target window with all overlays (including context menu)

```
public static BufferedImage capture(Pointer hWnd2, String wText) {
   HWND hWnd = new HWND(hWnd2);
   boolean success;
   if(User32Extra.INSTANCE.IsIconic(hWnd))
   {
       success= User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd, 4);
       System.err.println(success);
       System.err.println(wText+Native.getLastError());
   }
   // Pass GetDesktopWindow instead of target HWND to GetDC
   HDC hdcWindow2 = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow());
   HDC hdcMemDC = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow2);

   RECT bounds = new RECT();
   //RECT bounds1 = new RECT();
   User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hWnd, bounds);
   //User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetClientRect(hWnd, bounds1);

   //int extraGap = (bounds.right-bounds.left-bounds1.right);
   int width = bounds.right-bounds.left;
   int height = bounds.bottom-bounds.top;
   HBITMAP hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow2, width, height);

   HANDLE hOld = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hBitmap);
   GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC,0, 0, width, height, hdcWindow2, bounds.left, bounds.top, WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hOld);

   BITMAPINFO bmi = new BITMAPINFO();
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
   Memory buffer = new Memory(width * height * 4);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcWindow2, hBitmap, 0, height, buffer, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

   GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteDC(hdcMemDC);
   User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow2);

   return image;
}
```

This method, however, will capture other window if it is overlapping our target window. 
It is probably sufficient if you know that window is active or have context menu opened (because it will enforce it to be foreground) .

Another approach is a bit hacky, but it works for other scenarios. We can check if there are any windows with class name `#32768` (class for popup menus). If there is, we check whether our target window is foreground one, and then we can copy it to our target bitmap on top of our window.

```
public static BufferedImage capture(Pointer hWnd2, String wText) {
    HWND hWnd = new HWND(hWnd2);
    boolean success;
    if(User32Extra.INSTANCE.IsIconic(hWnd))
    {
        success= User32Extra.INSTANCE.ShowWindow(hWnd, 4);
        System.err.println(success);
        System.err.println(wText+Native.getLastError());
    }
    HDC hdcWindow2 = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hWnd);
    final HDC hdcMemDC = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow2);

    RECT bounds = new RECT();
    RECT bounds1 = new RECT();
    User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hWnd, bounds);
    User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetClientRect(hWnd, bounds1);

    int extraGap = (bounds.right-bounds.left-bounds1.right);
    int width = bounds.right-bounds.left-extraGap;
    int height = bounds.bottom-bounds.top-extraGap ;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow2, width, height);

    HANDLE hOld = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hBitmap);
    GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC,0, 0, width, height, hdcWindow2, bounds.left+bounds1.right-bounds.right+extraGap, bounds.top+bounds1.bottom-bounds.bottom+extraGap, WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY);

    // Popup menu doesn't have parent, so we could encounter situation when context menu from another window is overlapping our target window
    // Since context menu enforces our window to focus, we can check here if our window is foreground window (otherwise it is not possible to have opened context menu)
    if (User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow() == hWnd)
    {
        final RECT windowBounds = bounds;
        // Enum all windows and check if they have class #32768
        User32.INSTANCE.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
            @Override
            public boolean callback(HWND hMenuWnd, Pointer arg1) {
                byte[] windowClass = new byte[8];
                User32.INSTANCE.GetClassNameA(hMenuWnd, windowClass, 8);
                String wClass = Native.toString(windowClass);
                // #32768 is class name for popup menus.
                if (wClass.equals("#32768"))
                {
                    HDC hdcWindowMenu = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hMenuWnd);
                    RECT menuBounds = new RECT();
                    User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hMenuWnd, menuBounds);
                    GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC, menuBounds.left - windowBounds.left, menuBounds.top - windowBounds.top, menuBounds.right-menuBounds.left, menuBounds.bottom-menuBounds.top, hdcWindowMenu, 0, 0, WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY);
                    User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hMenuWnd, hdcWindowMenu);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }, null);
    }

    GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hOld);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = new BITMAPINFO();
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
    Memory buffer = new Memory(width * height * 4);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcWindow2, hBitmap, 0, height, buffer, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteDC(hdcMemDC);
    User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow2);

    return image;
}
```

For EnumWindows you have to add following import:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
```

and definition:

```
boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
int GetClassNameA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
```

Comment: If I want to capture a specific window, Why should I capture Desktop Window!

Comment: Did you try my code? It captures only your specified window, but copies it from screen HWND instead of window HWND. That way it will include all overlays, including context menus . It doesn't capture entire screen.

Comment: I am using that for screen share. If I use that my screen will be painted with the specified window.

Comment: Why would it be? This code doesn't paint anything, it just copies bitmap from screen to BufferedImage. Note that I removed PrintWindow call as it is not necessary to capture window. If that's not what you are looking for, please clarify your needs.

Comment: `GetDesktopWindow()` Captures the window which is on top position. That doesn't capture the specified HWND.

Comment: From MSDN: _The desktop window is the area on top of which other windows are painted._ This code works as follows: 1. It gets DC of the desktop window (which is entire screen). 2. It gets coordinates of your specified window (`hWnd`). 3. It copies pixels from screen DC, but only from the area of your `hWnd` window, so the result is ONLY your specified window. Not the entire screen.

Comment: 3. It copies the top most window which is visible on the screen, not the specified window. Note:- Top most window is not the specified window. I have tried it.

Comment: You're right, it is an issue for scenario like screen sharing. Check out my edited answer, I added alternative method.

Comment: Thanks! That is working but if I open sub context menu only sub context menu is being captured because findwindow finds single window i.e topmost window. How to get all the context menus?

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that I don't have java compiler on hand, so it might contain minor syntax errors. You should get the idea though.

Comment: A winrt modern version of this would be nice.